# Как сделать прокрутку содержимого липкого блока если его высота больше высоты браузера?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sidebar

```js
function sticky(){
var sidebar = $('.sidebar');
var sidebarHeight = sidebar.outerHeight(true);
var sidebarOffsetTop = sidebar.offset().top;
var parent = $('.flexCatalog');
var parentHeight = parent.outerHeight(true);
var parentOffsetTop = parent.offset().top;
var bottom = parent.offset().top + parent.outerHeight(true) - $(window).outerHeight(true);
var stop = parent.outerHeight(true) - $(window).outerHeight(true) - sidebarOffsetTop + parentOffsetTop;
var sideBarOffsetBottom = sidebarOffsetTop + sidebarHeight;


//alert(parentHeight + ',' + bottom + ', ' + stop + ', ');
$(window).on('scroll', function(){

var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

if (scroll >= sidebarOffsetTop && scroll <= bottom){

sidebar.addClass('sticky').css('top', '0');

}
else if(scroll >= sidebarOffsetTop && scroll >= bottom){

sidebar.removeClass('sticky').css('top', stop + 'px');

}
else{

sidebar.removeClass('sticky').css('top', '0');

}



});
}
$(window).on('load resize', function(){

sticky();

});
```

```css
html, body {
  min-height: 2000px;
  padding: 50px 0;
  margin: auto;
}


h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.content{
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}


 .posr{
  position: relative;
 }

.sidebar{
 z-index:20;
}

.sidebar.sticky{
 position: fixed;
}

.flexCatalog{
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-between;

 }

.partFirst{
 max-width: 30%;
flex-basis: 30%;
}

.partSecond{
 max-width: 60%;
 flex-basis: 60%;
 background: red;
}


.goods{
 height: 1581px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="content">
  <div class="flexCatalog">
<div class="partFirst posr">
<div class="sidebar posr">
<h2>Категории</h2>
<div>пункт</div>
<div>пункт</div>
<div>пункт</div>
<div>пункт</div>
<div>пункт</div>
<div>пункт</div>
<h2>Страны<br> производители</h2>
<div>Фильтр</div>
<div>Фильтр</div>
<div>Фильтр</div>
<div>Фильтр</div>
<div>Фильтр</div>
<div>Фильтр</div>
<div>Фильтр</div>
<div>Фильтр</div>
<div>Фильтр</div>
</div></div>
<div class="partSecond df">
<div class="goods"></div>
</div></div>
  </div>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Набросал такой липкий блок. Сразу скажу что плагины, пожалуйста, не предлагайте, не хочу их использовать, да и не нужны они тут.

Сейчас при достижении скролла до верха сайдбара ему дадим класс **sticky**, который имеет свойство **position: fixed** и если при скроллинге снизу окна браузера появится нижняя часть родителя (**offsetBottom**), то у сайдбара уберем класс **sticky** и добавим ему свойство **top со значением = высота родителя - высота окна браузера - сайбрар offset().top + родителя offset().top** (но это все мелочи)

Сейчас хотел бы попросить помощи чтобы понять как можно дописать условие так чтобы (сложно объяснить на пальцах) если при скроллинге высота сайдбара больше высоты окна браузера (например фильтров не видно, не влезают на весь экран), то мы не добавляем класс **sticky**, а ждем пока проскроллится до низа сайдбара и только тогда фиксируем его, но когда мы листам вверх, то ждём пока появится верх сайдбара и только тогда фиксируем его.

Наглядные примеры итога - сайдбары Вк, Фб
или вот ссылка на плагин https://abouolia.github.io/sticky-sidebar/#examples пример номер 2 "**Scrollable Sticky Element**" надеюсь понятно объяснил   как в итогу должно работать, весь вечер парюсь как же сделать, в гугле ответов на похожие вопросы не нашел

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тоже гуглил и ничего не нашел по этому поводу решил сделать сам.
Так вот. 
Отличная штука: `position: sticky;` 
Можешь подробнее погуглить про нее, но она не так работает как надо с высокими блоками, по этому надо немного дописать скрипт.

Делаем так. Надеюсь ты знаешь что такое бутстрап

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="sticky">Тот самый высокий блок</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-9"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

По css надо задать липкое позиционирование. Ну отступы чтоб красивее было.

```
.sticky{
  position: sticky;
  top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

А теперь js

```
  var lastscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if (lastscroll > $(window).scrollTop()) {
      stickyleftcol("up", lastscroll - $(window).scrollTop());
    } else {
      stickyleftcol("down", $(window).scrollTop() - lastscroll);
    }
    lastscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  });

function stickyleftcol(napravlenie, sceollpx) {
    if ($("div").is(".sticky")) {
      var raznh = $(".sticky").outerHeight() - window.innerHeight;
      if (raznh < 0) {
        raznh = 0;
      }
      if (napravlenie == "down") {
        $(".sticky").css("top", function (index, value) {
          var newSize = Number(value.replace("px", "")) - sceollpx;
          if (newSize < -raznh) {
            newSize = -raznh;
          }
          return newSize;
        });
      } else if (napravlenie == "up") {
        $(".sticky").css("top", function (index, value) {
          var newSize = Number(value.replace("px", "")) + sceollpx;
          if (newSize > 115) {
            newSize = 115;
          }
          return newSize;
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

Можно посмотреть как это работает [в проекте который я делаю](http://htmlcss.onebio.ru/socolor/catalog.html) (для тех кто будет смотреть в будущем, ссылка будет работать не вечно, так как это тестовый домен)

Comment: Здравствуйте, что насчет поддержки браузерами ***position:sticky***? Safary/chrome/opera/firefix/webkit?

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky

Comment: Спасибо, помог Ваш ответ разобраться что к чему в целом и получилось наконец-то сделать. ***position:sticky ONE LOVE***. Хвала небесам, что современные браузеры поддерживают это свойство теперь, на всякий случай добавил еще ***-webkit-sticky***. Если у кого-то не будет работать  ***position:sticky**, то тут надо знать что это свойство "стикуется" относительно родителя, то есть у родителя должна быть высота гораздо больше "стикуемого" элемента чтобы он мог именно по этой высоте кататься

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте этому элементу следующие свойства

```
max-height: 100vh; /* Если высота будет больше высоты вьюпорта браузера */
overflow-y: auto;  /* То у содержимого элемента будет scroll */
```

Пример:

```css
body {
  height: 300vh;
}

.overflow {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 350px;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 60px); /* 60px это top: 20px + bottom: 20px + padding: 10px*/
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background: gray;
  margin: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: sticky;
  top: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.overflow .content {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 330px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="overflow">
  <div class="content">
    Если открыть сниппет на "весь экран" то скролла не будет
  </div>
</div>
```